# Make - Apply rule to a dynamically created file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following rule:

```
%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.S
    $(CC) $(ASFLAGS) -c $< -o $(BINDIR)$@
```

It works great, except for the case where one of the source files `vectors.S` is created dynamically. The file does not come into existence until the following rule is ran:

```
vectors.S: $(SRCDIR)vectors.pl
    $(SRCDIR)vectors.pl > $(SRCDIR)vectors.S
```

The rule creates the file `src/vectors.S`. Why doesn't the previous rule get applied to this new file? (The default implicit rule is used instead). What can I do to make it apply?

For reference, here is a sample of the Makefile output:

```
gcc -m32 -gdwarf-2 -Wa,-divide -c src/swtch.S -o bin/swtch.o
gcc -m32 -gdwarf-2 -Wa,-divide -c src/trapasm.S -o bin/trapasm.o
src/vectors.pl > src/vectors.S
gcc -m32 -gdwarf-2 -Wa,-divide   -c -o vectors.o vectors.S
gcc: error: vectors.S: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [vectors.o] Error 4
```

**-- Update --**

I managed to get it to work by specifying an explicit rule for `vectors.o`:

```
vectors.o: vectors.S
    $(CC) $(ASFLAGS) -c $(SRCDIR)$< -o $(BINDIR)$@
```

I am still curious **why** the custom `%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.S` rule is ignored and the implicit one chosen... And what (if any) is the standard way to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ignored because it's not building the right file.

The file `vector.S` is not the same file as `src/vector.S`.  You have asked make to build `src/vector.S` by listing it as a prerequisite, and you've defined a rule that tells make how to build `vector.S`, but that rule is useless to make because that's not the file you want to build.

The Second Rule of Makefiles says, a recipe should always update the target you told make it would, which is `$@`.  If your recipe updates something other than just exactly `$@`, then it's wrong.

So, you want your rules to be this:

```
$(BINDIR)%.o: $(SRCDIR)%.S
        $(CC) $(ASFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(SRCDIR)vectors.S: $(SRCDIR)vectors.pl
        $(SRCDIR)vectors.pl > $@
```

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the clarification. I didn't know the rule target could be a path.

Comment: Yes... the target is the actual thing you want to build.  It's not an abstract name for it.